# Alternativa al if en java 2.0

Tags: java

Hola buenas anteriormente necesitaba hacer un código como este:

```
#Entrada (numero entero del 1 al 10)
#Salida en texto (se ha introducido el numero cinco
```

Ejemplo

```
#Introduzco el numero 6
#Haz introducido el numero "seis"
```

Descubrí gracias a dos usuarios aquí que se podía hacer gracias a un array y un numero que imprimía la posición de la array que me interesaba gracias al siguiente código:

```
public static void main(String[]args) {
        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            ArrayList<String> numeros = new ArrayList<String>();
            numeros.add("Cero");
            numeros.add("Uno");
            numeros.add("Dos");
            numeros.add("Tres");
            numeros.add("Cuatro");
            numeros.add("Cinco");
            numeros.add("Seis");
            numeros.add("Siete");
            numeros.add("Ocho");
            numeros.add("Nueve");
            numeros.add("Diez");
            int intro;
            System.out.println("Introdue un numero del 1 al 10 para saber como se escribe");
            intro = sc.nextInt();
            if (intro > 10 && intro < 0){
                System.out.println("Numero incorrecto");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println(numeros.get(intro));
            }
        }
    }
```

Ahora viene mi problema y es que quería saber si puedo hacer lo mismo pero al revés es decir que el usuario meta el numero en letras y el programa le devolviese el numero entero me refiero:

```
#Introduzco el numero "seis"
#Haz introducido el numero 6
```

Lo suyo seria no hacerlo ni con if ni con switch a menos que no haya una alternativa mas simple. Gracias de antemano

Comment: No existen conversiones directas entre un texto y un número. Piensa que el texto puede estar en cualquier idioma. Para relacionar "cero" y 0 deberás crear condiciones. Por ejemplo: `if("cero".equalsIgnoreCase(texto)) return 0;`

Comment: Vamos que al final voy a tener que hacerlo con if. Bueno voy a escribir unas cuantas condiciones gracias <3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Para obtener el nombre de un número

Puedes definir un array de cadenas con cada valor y luego buscar por el índice:

```
String[] nameOfNumbers = {
        "cero", "uno", "dos", "tres", "cuatro", "cinco", 
        "seis", "siete", "ocho", "nueve", "diez"
    };
```

Y luego:

```
intro = sc.nextInt();
try 
{
    System.out.println(nameOfNumbers[intro]);
}
catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception) 
{
    System.out.println("Número incorrecto");
}
```

El bloque `try ... catch` permitirá que tu código funcione sustituyendo cada valor existente en `nameOfNumbers`. Así, si quisieras también el `once`, lo agregas en la posición que le corresponde, al final del actual `nameOfNumbers`. Con el `try ... catch` no necesitas esto: `if (intro > 10 && intro < 0){` pero si es una exigencia de un ejercicio lo lo que sea, quita el bloque `try ... catch`.

Cabe decir que esto funciona porque en Java, como en casi todos los lenguajes, los arrays empiezan en el índice `0`, entonces en `nameOfNumbers` simplemente asignamos el nombre que correspondería a cada valor numérico. Para programas más exigentes, en los que necesites convertir cualquier número a letras o viceversa, existen bibliotecas que ya lo hacen<sup>1</sup>, tomando en cuenta aspectos tan cambiantes como el idioma.

#### Para obtener el número partiendo de la letra

Puedes crear un `HashMap` que asocie cada valor numérico a un nombre (esto al revés te serviría para resolver lo expuesto en el primer caso).

```
Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("cero",0);
    map.put("uno",1);
    map.put("dos",2);
    map.put("tres",3);
    map.put("cuatro",4);
    map.put("cinco",5);
    map.put("seis",6);
    map.put("siete",7);        
    map.put("ocho",8);
    map.put("nueve",9);
    map.put("diez",10);
```

Luego, buscarías el valor asociado a esa key. Por ejemplo:

```
String introS="tres";
if(map.containsKey(introS))
{
    System.out.printf("En letras %d equivale a %s",map.get(introS),introS);
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Número incorrecto");
}
```

**Salida:**

```
En letras 3 equivale a tres
```

---

#### Notas

1. Ver por ejemplo las siguientes:

   - [ICU4J](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/icu4j/)
   - [tradukisto](https://github.com/allegro/tradukisto)
   - [Integer-To-Words-Java](https://github.com/busaeed/Integer-To-Words-Java/blob/master/NumberInWords.java)

Comment: Me puedes decir alguna biblioteca con la que se pueda convertir numeros a letras y letras a nueros porfavor?

Comment: @Anthonyx82 ahora te paso un link y te pongo un ejemplo de lo contrario basado en `HashMap`.

Comment: Vale gracias <3

Answer (score 1):

Una alternativa algo más limpia es utilizar el Optional de Java 8+.

Algo así:

```
private Optional<Integer> getValueFromNumberString(String theNumber) {
    Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("cero", 0);
    map.put("uno", 1);
    map.put("dos", 2);
    map.put("tres", 3);
    map.put("cuatro", 4);
    map.put("cinco", 5);
    map.put("seis", 6);
    map.put("siete",7);
    map.put("ocho", 8);
    map.put("nueve", 9);
    map.put("diez", 10);

    return Optional.ofNullable(map.get(theNumber.toLowerCase()));
}

private String stringToNumberMessage(int theValue, String theNumber) {
    return theNumber + " in numeric form is " + theValue;
}

private String errorMessage() {
    return "Number string not found";
}
```

Y después, para invocarlo, por ejemplo con el "cuatro":

```
    String theNumberinLetters = "cuatro";
    System.out.println(getValueFromNumberString(theNumberinLetters)
        .map((i) -> stringToNumberMessage(i, theNumberinLetters))
        .orElseGet(this::errorMessage));
```

Una buena guía aquí: https://dzone.com/articles/using-optional-correctly-is-not-optional